# How to fix players moving further and further each time keypressed

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, 2d-games

Over time as I move the two players in the Air Hockey game, they move further and further on each keypress, does anyone know why?

This is my draw function (the one being run over and over again by the setInterval call at the bottom). Also just a snippet of the whole file, message me if the rest of the file is needed for context :)

```
       //this function is run over and over again, clearing the board and re-writing what is being executed
    function draw () {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // redraw everything that was drawn earlier
        drawBoard();

        //redraw the player mallets and ball with modified coordinates
        drawFilledCircle(p1Mallet.x, p1Mallet.y, p1Mallet.radius, 1);
        drawFilledCircle(p2Mallet.x, p2Mallet.y, p2Mallet.radius, 2);
        drawFilledCircle(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, 0);

        //function to move player 1 mallet: pressing w, a, s, d makes mallet move 
        addEventListener("keydown", function movePlayers (event) {

            //if these keycodes are pressed, player 1 moves
            if (event.keyCode == 68) {
            p1Mallet.x += 0.1;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 65) {
                p1Mallet.x -= 0.1;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 83) {
                p1Mallet.y += 0.1;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 87) {
                p1Mallet.y -= 0.1;
            }

            //if these keycodes are pressed, player 2 moves
            if (event.keyCode == 39) {
                p2Mallet.x += 0.1;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 37) {
                p2Mallet.x -= 0.1;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 40) {
                p2Mallet.y += 0.1;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 38) {
                p2Mallet.y -= 0.1;
            }
        });

        //if the ball is within the goal lines (anywhere on the board)
        if (ball.y > 200 && ball.y < 400) {

            //if the x coordinate of the ball is past the black line on the right side, player 1 scores
            if (ball.x + xSpeed > canvas.width - 2*ball.radius - 30) {
                console.log("Player 1 Score");
                ball.x = canvas.width/2;
                ball.y = canvas.height/2;
                xSpeed = 0;
                ySpeed = 0;
                player_1_Score = player_1_Score + 1;
            }
            //if the x coordinate of the ball is past the black line on the left side, player 2 scores
            else if (ball.x + xSpeed < 2*ball.radius + 30) {
                console.log("Player 2 Score");
                ball.x = canvas.width/2;
                ball.y = canvas.height/2;
                xSpeed = 0;
                ySpeed = 0;
                player_2_Score = player_2_Score + 1;
            }
        }

        //bounce off wall logic: if the position of the ball is past these dimensions, make the speed of the ball opposite so it goes the other way
        if (ball.x + xSpeed >= canvas.width - ball.radius*2 - 30 || ball.x + xSpeed <= ball.radius*2 + 30)  {
            xSpeed *= -1;
        }
        else if (ball.y + ySpeed >= canvas.height - ball.radius*2 - 30 || ball.y + ySpeed <= ball.radius*2 + 30) {
            ySpeed *= -1;
        }

        //for player 1 to not be able to move off the screen
        if (p1Mallet.x > canvas.width - p1Mallet.radius*2 - 30) {
            p1Mallet.x = 1160;
        }
        else if (p1Mallet.x <= p1Mallet.radius*2 + 30) {
            p1Mallet.x = 90;
        }
        if (p1Mallet.y > canvas.height - p1Mallet.radius*2 - 30) {
            p1Mallet.y = 510;
        }
        else if (p1Mallet.y <= p1Mallet.radius*2 + 30) {
            p1Mallet.y = 90;
        }

        //for player 2 to not be able to move off the screen
        if (p2Mallet.x > canvas.width - p2Mallet.radius*2 - 30) {
            p2Mallet.x = 1160;
        }
        else if (p2Mallet.x <= p2Mallet.radius*2 + 30) {
            p2Mallet.x = 90;
        }
        if (p2Mallet.y > canvas.height - p2Mallet.radius*2 - 30) {
            p2Mallet.y = 510;
        }
        else if (p2Mallet.y <= p2Mallet.radius*2 + 30) {
            p2Mallet.y = 90;
        }

        //determines whether or not mallet & ball make contact. Uses distance function from earlier to calculate values based on current ball & mallet positioning. 
        var p1Dist = distance(p1Mallet.x, p1Mallet.y, ball.x, ball.y);
        var p2Dist = distance(p2Mallet.x, p2Mallet.y, ball.x, ball.y);

        //for Player 1
        //if the value calculated from the distance function is less than 55 (mallet & ball make contact). 55 is the sum of the ball radius & mallet radius.
        if (p1Dist <= 55) {

            //calculate difference in ball and mallet positioning
            var d1x = ball.x - p1Mallet.x;
            var d1y = ball.y - p1Mallet.y;

            //divide the difference by 20 because multiplying by 55 in the method below would be too fast a speed for the ball
            d1x /= 20;
            d1y /= 20;

            //calculate the speed at which the ball moves away by multiplying the slowed down difference above by ballSpeed (10)
            xSpeed = d1x*ballSpeed;
            ySpeed = d1y*ballSpeed;
        }

        //for Player 2
        //if the value calculated from the distance function is less than 55 (mallet & ball make contact). 55 is the sum of the ball radius & mallet radius.
        if (p2Dist <= 55) {

            //calculate difference in ball and mallet positioning
            var d2x = ball.x - p2Mallet.x;
            var d2y = ball.y - p2Mallet.y;

            //divide the difference by 20 because multiplying by 55 would be too fast a speed for the ball
            d2x /= 20;
            d2y /= 20;

            //calculate the speed at which the ball moves away by multiplying the slowed down difference above by ballSpeed (10)
            xSpeed = d2x*ballSpeed;
            ySpeed = d2y*ballSpeed;
        }

        //ball's x position will increase/decrease speed each time draw function is ran based on what value is in the xSpeed variable
        ball.x += xSpeed;
        //ball's y position will increase/decrease speed each time draw function is ran based on what value is in the ySpeed variable
        ball.y += ySpeed;
        //xSpeed of ball will multiply itself by 0.99 each time draw function is ran to slow down after a hit
        xSpeed *= 0.99;
        //ySpeed of ball will multiply itself by 0.99 each time draw function is ran to slow down after a hit
        ySpeed *= 0.99;
    }

    //calls draw function to begin game, with value after it determining how fast the game is played
    window.setInterval(draw, 10);
```

I would like the two players to move a consistent amount each time a key is pressed

Comment: You keep adding event listeners, each of which will run, each of which increments the position.

Comment: @DaveNewton if i used the addEventListener for keyPress, how should I rearrange? do i remove it completely? sorry i am a beginner

Comment: You should add it only once.

Comment: Hey it's fixed! Thank you for your help